# Difficulty to execute ionic build ios

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

For some strange reason today I could build my project, running `ionic build ios` received this error.

Try removing the platform and reinstall.
 All plugins you uninstall and reinstall but nothing came back.

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
Ld build/emulator/myApp.app/myApp normal i386
(1 failure)
error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: What is the "1 failure"? Can you provide more information about it? Today many users have problems with building their apps.

Comment: Sorry, edit my post!

Comment: That's not enough information.  What is the linker error?

Comment: Only I get that error and also the following: You may not have any OS or the environment required to build esta project. I do not receive any other message.

Comment: Are you on a computer running OSX with Xcode installed?

Comment: If, now in this moment I am upgrading my OS X to see if that can help, I found some answers on the internet that had to do with the installed version. Now I have another problem, that of this if you have not found a solution. I leave in my publication details and you commented when the update is done